# Passing a backing bean instance as parameter to composite component

Tags: jsf, el, jsf-2.2, composite-component

Is it possible to pass a backing bean instance as parameter to a composite component using JSF 2.2 and invoke methods from the bean instance?

Is there any examples? Thanks for helping.

Comment: what do you mean by " send a backing bean instance " ?

Comment: Instead of sending just an attribute of a backing bean, I would like to send the whole backing bean instance and invoke its methods within the custom component.

Comment: @Mifmif means if you can send an instance of a managed bean through Expression Language to a custom component in form of `<cc:mycc action="#{bean.foo(anotherBean)}" />`.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza if so, so yes it's possible :)

Comment: already done , don't care.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza, thanks for helping. But, if possible, I'd like to send a backing bean instance like `<cc:mycc backingBeanInstance="#{bean}" />` and within the custom component, invoke a method from the instance like `<h:commanButton action="#{beanReceivedFromParameter.myPolimorphicMethod}"/>`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got it! And here is my solution:

Composite component:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
    xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
    xmlns:cc="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite">

    <cc:interface>
        <cc:attribute name="backingBean" required="true" shortDescription="A backing bean to invoke polimorphic methods."/>
    </cc:interface>

    <cc:implementation>
        <h:commandButton value="Foo" action="#{cc.attrs.backingBean.myPolimorphicMethod}"/>     
    </cc:implementation>

</html>
```

Using the composite component:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
    xmlns:cc="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/composite/components"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
    template="/WEB-INF/templates/template.xhtml">

    <ui:define name="content">
        <h:form>
            <cc:myCustomComponent backingBean="#{myBacking}"></cc:myCustomComponent>
        </h:form>
    </ui:define>

</ui:composition>
```